# Example of using String.format() with a number / does this function even work?

Tags: apex, string, formatting, platform-bug

Per the [docs](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_format)

> **format(String, List<String>)**
>
> Treat the current string as a pattern that should be used for substitution in the same manner as `apex:outputText`.

Which would lead me to think this would be a great function

```
public static String toCurrencyString(Decimal input) {
    return String.format('{0,number,currency}', new String[] { input.format());
}
```

But that just throws a `System.StringException: Cannot format given Object as a Number`

Is there anyway to use this function for more than just basic string substitution? Or should I just consider this apparent platform bug one of those special Salesforce "features" that will never get fixed.

Comment: I think String.format accepts only strings... Check http://www.tgerm.com/2011/01/message-format-string-format-apex.html ?

Comment: Sigh I was afraid of that. Blerg, I hate these holes. Probably expecting too much in hoping they could fix the docs, so at least they don't imply functionality they don't actually have.

Comment: If you wanted to post an answer of "No" and add a link to the idea to vote for the feature, I'd accept it.  Stuck waiting for the wait period to answer my own question to expire.

Comment: I was disappointed to find this out myself. I would have thought they'd accept an array of objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.format()` seems to accept only Strings as arguments, it's less powerful than `apex:outputText`.

Check the [@Abhinav](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/266/abhinav-gupta)'s blog post at http://www.tgerm.com/2011/01/message-format-string-format-apex.html, vote for his [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000KlHoAAK)...

I think for now your best choice is this:

```
Decimal x = 123456789.01;
System.debug(x.format());
```

It outputs `123,456,789.01` in my current `en_GB` locale. Different locales (like `de`) can have dots and commas swapped around.

Comment: [Decimal].format() formats the Decimal value into the locale of the current user. Is there a way of formatting a Decimal to an arbitrary locale (or format) in Apex? e.g. Decimal decimalValue = 10000.00; String stringValue = decimalValue.format('###,###,##0.00');

Comment: @cyorkston not that I'm aware of. You'll have to roll out your own formatter, for example round down the number to cut into main & fractional part, then merge back with separators you need. Some dividing by 1000 until & adding comma till there's nothing to divide? Maybe you'll find some formatting functions or ideas at https://code.google.com/archive/p/apex-lang/ although the project is abandoned since 2012 and many functions it "patches" are now in core String library.